# Matlab: calculating the mean of an array nested in a struct

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have a struct call CDF of 3 fields with are all double arrays, size 1x48. (below)
[image]

I need to get the average (or mean) of the cdfSR field but across each struct element. If I'm not being clear enough I need

```
[ sum(CDF(:).cdfSR(1))/895, sum(CDF(:).cdfSR(2))/895, ..., sum(CDF(:).cdfSR(48))/895 ]
```

Each time I try to implement "CDF(:).cdfSR(1)", I receive an error:

**Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 895 results.**

However, I want all 895 results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
CDF(:).cdfSR(1)
```

returns a comma-separated list with each of the `ii=1:895` elements `CDF(ii).cdfSR(1)`. You can capture these using square brackets:

```
[CDF(:).cdfSR(1)]
```

is equivalent to

```
[CDF(1).cdfSR(1), CDF(2).cdfSR(1), CDF(3).cdfSR(1), ...]
```

So the code you posted can be written as:

```
[ sum([CDF(:).cdfSR(1)])/895, sum([CDF(:).cdfSR(2)])/895, ..., sum([CDF(:).cdfSR(48)])/895 ]
```

But of course this is not viable either. Since `CDF(ii).cdfSR` is a horizontal vector, I suggest you concatenate them vertically:

```
vertcat(CDF(:).cdfSR)
```

`vertcat(a,b,c)` is the same as `[a;b;c]`. You can also use `cat(1,...)`.

This leads to a 895x48 double array. You can take the mean using `mean`:

```
mean(vertcat(CDF(:).cdfSR), 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  mean(vertcat(CDF(:).cdfSR), 1)  did the trick!

Comment: Doh! Of course, mean over first dimension. Fixed that in the answer. Thanks!